# Ignoring specific rows in SAS

Tags: import, sas, rows

I have a large excel file that I am importing to SAS; Row 1 has the variable names but rows 2-4 of the file have additional descriptive information (about the variables) that I do not want in my SAS dataset. Is there a way to exclude those 3 rows while importing or after importing the data onto SAS?

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain how it did not meet your needs. Can you get the file as CSV instead of an actual Excel binary file?  You will have much more flexibility in reading a text file.

Comment: Try reading the file twice. First read it as is to get the variable names. Then read it again specifying the RANGE option to start at A5:0 which will read all the data but with default names. Then you can use some code to rename the data as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data looks like this in Excel:

[image]

Use the option `datarow=5` in `proc import` to specify that your data starts on row 5. `proc import` will automatically pull the names in row 1, then skip down to row 5 to start reading data.

```
proc import 
    file = '/location/have.xlsx'
    out  = want
    dbms = xlsx
    replace;
    datarow = 5;
run;
```

Output:

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
1       2       3
4       5       6
```

Comment: Thank you. I have multiple sheets in my xls file and included the option RANGE to specify the sheet name, but it says that the statement is invalid.

Comment: Use the `sheet=` option to name a specific sheet. You can loop through multiple sheets using a macro if needed.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Great to hear. If this answer is acceptable for you, marking it as accepted would be a big help to others who search for this problem.

Comment: Rather than `datarow = 3;`, I had to use `range="sheet0$A3:0";`